# How to dynamically update erb textarea

Tags: html, ruby, erb

I want to update a html textarea with the contents of a file on the server. The problem is the file gets updated on the server very often and I want the user to have the latest version all the time (every 100 milliseconds to be precise). Currently what I'm using

```
<%= IO.read("file_name") %>
```

and the problem is the file will be read only once (when the user enters the url). Also because of the specifics of my task refreshing the page is not an option.

If it matters I'm using Sinatra on Thin server with Ruby 2.0.

Comment: Can't you use an Ajax request to read the file contents and update the textarea with the new file contents ? I have never done a Sinatra app, but Ajax with Jquery must be trivial to include.

Comment: I have posted the solution in the answer box. Feel free to ask questions if any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to learn to write a Sinatra app and that took little time. Here is the solution which works and I am using ERB templates in this code snippet

**my_app.rb (Main sinatra application file)**

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'json'
get '/' do
  f = File.open("/home/abcd/my_file.txt","r")
  @contents = f.read()
  f.close()
  erb :home
end
get '/read_file' do 
  f = File.open("/home/abcd/my_file.txt","r")
  contents = f.read()
  f.close()
  if request.xhr?
       halt 200, {:file_contents => contents}.to_json
  else 
     erb :read_file
  end
end
```

**views/home.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="data"><%= @contents %></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function update_data() {
  $.ajax({
 url: "/read_file",
 accepts: "application/json",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function(data) {
    $("#data").html(data.file_contents);
 }
  });
   }
   $(document).ready(function() {
#Call update_data every 10 seconds
setInterval(update_data, 10000);
})
</script>
```

Thank you for asking for code snippet. I learnt a new thing today. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your effort. I tried the code and it doesn't seem to work for some reason (when I change the contents of my_file.txt the page doesn't get updated after waiting if I don't refresh). Is there something I might be missing?

Comment: 1. Do you see any Ajax request being fired in your browser's Javascript console (Firebug or equivalent)? 

2. If there is an error in the setInterval function also, nothing happens. So, please put an alert in the function that you are calling from the setInterval() and see if the function is actually getting called. 

3. After fixing 1 and 2, if the problem still exists, please review the response returned by the Ajax call.

4. Finally, put some logging statements in your sinatra app file to see if the behaviour is as expected.

Comment: update_data() didn't fire at all. However with some modifications I managed to make it work, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery setInterval would probably work:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.get('file_name', function(data){
        $('#div').html(data);
    });
},10000);
```

Though I'd suggest not writing the function in setInterval() and only reference it. E.G.

```
function readFile() {
    $.get('file_name', function(data){
        $('#div').html(data);
    });
}
setInterval(readFile, 10000);
```